# git diff ignore semicolon at end of line

Tags: git, git-diff

A colleague has created a commit where his editor has appended semicolons to each line (amongst other changes).

I know that I can use the `-w` switch to ignore whitespace errors. Would there be some kind of `git` magic to make git ignore `;` altogether, or even better only when at EOL ?

Something like:

```
git diff --ignore=; -w
```

Comment: possibly with a [`post-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) hook?

Comment: If ```| grep``` doesn't meet your needs, maybe ```git diff -G``` or ```grepdiff``` can do the job (https://linux.die.net/man/1/grepdiff)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can solve that with the `--word-diff-regex` option. This is what I did: I created a simple file and committed it with the following content.

```
first line
second line
third line
```

Then I modified it like this:

```
first line;
second; line;
third changed line;
```

If I have correctly understood, you need to show only the following differences:
second -> second;
third line -> third changed line

You can partially do this executing:

```
git diff  --word-diff-regex='[^ \\n;]+' HEAD..HEAD~1
```

And this is the output:

```
first line
second line
third[-changed-] line
```

I said partially because even if I found a regex to detect also the first change (`'[^ \\n]+(?!\\n|$)'`), git does not seem to accept it, for some reason I am not aware of (I am still working on it).

Anyway, the logic behind it is that this option "overrides" how git considers a word. I know this is not the right regex since it is not covering several cases, change it based on your needs (for example if you consider `test1;test2` a word).

Comment: thanks for the hint. You can make your answer better: `\\n` is not working.
What is working: `--word-diff-regex='[^;[:space:]]+'`.
But that is still a partial answer as you say; it ignores all semicolons, but it is  a nice help already

Comment: Thank you for the improvement. However, after some tries, I am afraid regex lookahead is not supported. The partial answer will probably remain partial. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yes I understood that, you have my upvote already, but I'm not accepting the answer as for now...

Comment: Do not worry, I totally understand that. I just hope someone else will come up with a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of is :

create a file, with your colleague's version, where you remove the semicolons at EOL, and compare that with the file you want :

```
git show modifiedcommit:the/file | sed -e 's/;$//' > /tmp/theFile
git diff originalcommit:the/file /tmp/theFile
```